# Define a JavaScript function to be called from Emscripten JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, c++, webassembly, emscripten

```
function myGreeting()
{
    console.log('666666666666666666666 function myGreeting');
}

mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, {
//  myGreeting: function()
//  {
//      console.log('666666666666666666666 function myGreeting');
//  },
    TestFunction555__sig: 'v',
    TestFunction555:  function () 
    {
        console.log('55555555555555555555555');
        myGreeting();
    },
});
```

This JS code is linked to C++ code using Emscripten and I can call `TestFunction555` from C++. Now I am trying to add another JS functions `myGreeting` and call it from `TestFunction555`. I tried to add it inside mergeInto (commented out) and also in global scope. For both cases I am getting `myGreeting() is not found` error.
Can you hint how I should define `myGreeting()` function?

Comment: when property `myGreeting` is uncommented, does `this` work? `this.myGreeting()`

Comment: @GrafiCode No `Uncaught TypeError: this.myGreeting is not a function`

Comment: I made `myGreeting` accessible from C++ similar to `TestFunction555` and also called it from C++ (so it is not optimized out). Then I can call it from JavaScript. But I think there should be better solution.

Comment: how about 'TestFunction555__deps:["myGreeting"]' ?
https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#implement-a-c-api-in-javascript